# How do I conditionally highlight dates within a start and end date range based on individual date rows?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

so I have this workbook that I am trying to figure out how to manage in a more automated way.

I have 2 main sheets. In 'Sheet2' there are 4 columns (Item, Sub-Item, Start, End). In 'Sheet1' there is similar data just formatted differently. Each valid permutation of Item and Sub-Item is already listed and the dates are expanded. Under each permutation of item/subitem I want to be able to enter 'True' if the date is affected and have it highlight any matching affected rows in 'Sheet2'. To be a match it needs to match the Item and Sub-Item and have a highlighted date that falls within the date range (exclusive of the End date) in 'Sheet2'. It doesn't have to be done in google sheets, it could also be done in excel if that makes it any easier or different.

I've linked a sample sheet below. Hopefully that helps clear up any questions.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Smsxr5_qsj0hLhc5oIJHsX-ISpB9p66vc1z4wOd3CNk/edit

Comment: Can you simplify your explanation? You have duplicate item and subitem in `sheet2`, how you will handle duplicate?

Comment: @Harun24hr yes, sorry, it's a little complicated but `Sheet2` is a non unique list so duplicates are acceptable. `Sheet1` should dictate what rows in `Sheet2` get highlighted regardless of what duplicates may exist in `Sheet2`. Does that help? I will try and think over how to more clearly and simply ask my question.

Comment: Could you please verify if my understanding of your problem is correct. You will write TRUE to Sheet1 and it should highlight the corresponding item to Sheet2. It should match the Item, Sub Item and the sheet1 date in between 2 dates in sheet2? Also, I was thinking of solving this using Google Apps Script, do you consider using it?

Comment: Yes that is correct @NikkoJ. the only thing to make sure of is that the end date is not included so it should only be considered if a date falls within the start date and End date minus one and yes google apps script is fine, it is probably something I should learn to use more confidently

Comment: @LarryFlores - What is your workaround for example a date falls under row 10 and row 11 of Sheet 2? There are some items in sheet2 that overlap on dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this:

Here I created an onEdit Trigger that will execute a function whenever an edit in Sheet was made and used its property to determine the item, sub-item, and date. Then compare it to each row in Sheet2. I added comment to each line of code to explain the process.

**Code:**

```
function isInBetween(t, s, e){
  let target = new Date(t); //convert target date to date format
  let start = new Date(s); //convert start date to date format
  let end = new Date(e); //convert end date to date format
  if(target.getTime() >= start.getTime() && target.getTime() < end.getTime()){ // check if target date is in between of start and end -1
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  let range = e.range; //get the range of edited cell
  let sheet = range.getSheet() //get the sheet of edited cell
  let row = range.getRow(); //get the row of edited cell
  let column = range.getColumn(); //get the column of edited cell
  
  if(row > 5 && column > 1 && column < 7 && sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.value == 'TRUE'){ //check whether the edited cell is in the editable range in sheet1
  
    let sheetItem = sheet.getRange(1, column).getDisplayValue(); //get the corresponding item of the edited cell
    let sheetSubItem = sheet.getRange(4, column).getDisplayValue(); //get the corresponding sub item of the edited cell
    let dateToCheck = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getDisplayValue(); //get the date of edited cell
    let sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); 
    let data = sheet2.getRange(2, 1, sheet2.getLastRow()-1, 4).getDisplayValues(); //get all values in sheet2
    data.forEach(function(row, i) { //iterate each values in sheet2
      let sheet2Item = row[0]; //get the item in sheet2
      let sheet2SubItem = row[1]; //get the sub item in sheet2
      let start = row[2].replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), '/'); //replace the '-' of start date with '/' 
      let end = row[3].replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), '/'); //replace the '-' of end date with '/' 
      if(sheetItem == sheet2Item && sheetSubItem == sheet2SubItem && isInBetween(dateToCheck, start, end)){ // this will check if the item, subitem of sheet1 matches in sheet2, this will also check if the date is in between
        sheet2.getRange(i+2, 1, 1, 4).setBackground("#b7e1cd"); //change the color of affected row in sheet2 to green
      }  
    })
    
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

### References:

- [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)